# Array version of allocation function

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, variadic-templates, allocation

There is a allocation function which returns the smart pointer to memory pool allocated and constructed single instance of T:

```
template<typename T, typename... ARGUMENTS>
std::unique_ptr<T, HeapDeleter<T>> allocate_unique( ARGUMENTS&&... arguments ) {

    HeapAllocator<T> allocator;

    /* Allocate memory in memory pool */
    T* ptr = allocator.template allocate<1>();

    if( ptr != nullptr ) {
        /* Construct T in allocated memory */
        ::new( static_cast<void*>( ptr ) ) T( std::forward<ARGUMENTS>( arguments )... );
    }

    return std::unique_ptr<T, HeapDeleter<T>>( ptr, HeapDeleter<T>() );
}
```

I am trying to implement an array variant of that capable to allocate N elements of T having a style of usage consistency of such function in mind. It would be great to keep the forwarding of ARGUMENTS... arguments in there but apply that for all the instances. Is there any option to do so?

```
template<typename T, typename... ARGUMENTS, std::size_t N>
std::unique_ptr<T[], HeapDeleter<T, N>> allocate_array( /* ??? */ ) { /* <--- */
    HeapAllocator<T> allocator;

    /* Allocate memory in memory pool */
    T* ptr = allocator.template allocate<N>();

    if( ptr != nullptr ) {
        std::ptrdiff_t idx = 0;

        /* Run T's move constructor for all the elements */
        ( ::new( static_cast<void*>( ptr + idx++ ) ) T( std::forward<ARGUMENTS>( arguments ) ), ... );
    }
    return std::unique_ptr<T, HeapDeleter<T>>( ptr, HeapDeleter<T>() );
}
```

Many thanks to anybody willing to help me... Martin

Comment: Should each element in the array be initialized with the exact same arguments? Then how about just a simple loop wrapping the placement `new`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: All the elements should be initialized with the same argument types but with different values...

Comment: I would also think a little bit about the order of the template arguments for the `allocate_array` function. Placing the size last means you need to explicitly define all the argument types first, which could otherwise be deduced.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok, the order of template arguments does not really matter, but thanks of for the hint. But how to define the function argument list to provide the values? Something like "array version of" `ARGUMENTS&&... arguments`

Comment: Then it's going to be very hard, if not impossible, since you don't really know which arguments to use for which object in the array. As far as I know you forward *all* arguments to the constructor, or *none*. I don't think you can forward `X` arguments, where `X` really is unknown.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You can use tuples and `std::forward_as_tuple` to tell that.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, but how do you get a tuple matching the `T` constructor? Especially if there are multiple overloaded constructors for `T`? Or do you mean that the caller of `allocate_array` passes multiple tuples instead?

Comment: Do you want a single set of arguments to be forwarded to all array element constructor calls? Or, multiple sets of arguments, each forwarded for a single element construction? The former is not possible, the latter is. But not directly, you can use tuples. It's similar to what `std::pair` does for piece-wise construction.

Comment: I meant multiple sets of arguments each forwarded to single element construction. The usage of std::tuple looks promising. How would the function declaration look like?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I meant that the caller will pass multiple tuples. Such as `allocate_array<std::string>(std::forward_as_tuple("hello"), std::forward_as_tuple(3, ' '), std::forward_as_tuple("world"));` I believe it is doable, just likely a bit complicated.

Comment: @DanielLangr Ah yes, probably doable. But I think that "a *bit* complicated" is a *bit* of an understatement... :)

Comment: ... means a design failure, or?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right :). I tried to do it, you might want to see my answer and check if there are any flaws.

Comment: BTW, would't be better to use `std::vector` with a custom allocator that allocates memory from memory pool? Then, you could forward arguments simply by `emplace_back`.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be great to keep the forwarding of ARGUMENTS... arguments in there but apply that for all the instances. Is there any option to do so?

No.

You can forward only one time because you can move only one time.

Suppose an argument is a `string &&`.

Forwarding it, you say the `T` constructor that it can use the memory allocated in it, leaving it (I presume) empty.

When you forward it for the second time, the string is empty.

Comment: The intention is to forward one set of arguments one during the construction of single element, having multiple sets of arguments for multiple elements...

Comment: @MartinKopecký - Sorry: not clear to me (maybe because English isn't my language). Please, can you add a simple code example to show what do you want?

Comment: @MartinKopecký: "*The intention is to forward one set of arguments one during the construction of single element, having multiple sets of arguments for multiple elements*" And how exactly would that happen? How would it know how many arguments the constructor would take? Without that knowledge, it wouldn't be able to break the list down into "sets of arguments".

Answer (score 1):

I did an attempt to resolve the problem as discussed in the comments. For the sake of simplicity, I used only raw pointers:

```
template <typename T, typename... Vs, size_t... Is>
void allocate_helper(T* ptr, std::tuple<Vs...> v, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
   new (ptr) T(std::forward<Vs>(std::get<Is>(v))...); 
}

template <typename T, typename V> 
void allocate_array_helper(T* ptr, V v)
{
   allocate_helper<T>(ptr, std::move(v), 
                      std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<V>>{});
}

template <typename T, typename V, typename... Vs>
void allocate_array_helper(T* ptr, V v, Vs... vs)
{
   allocate_helper<T>(ptr, std::move(v), 
                      std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<V>>{});
   try
   {
      allocate_array_helper<T>(++ptr, std::move(vs)...);
   }
   catch (...)
   {
      std::destroy_at(ptr);
      throw;
   }
}

template <typename T, typename... Vs>
T* allocate_array(Vs... vs)
{
   T* ptr = (T*)::operator new(sizeof(T) * sizeof...(Vs));
   try 
   {
      allocate_array_helper<T>(ptr, std::move(vs)...);
   }
   catch (...)
   { 
      ::operator delete(ptr);
      throw;
   }
   return ptr;
}
```

It works for me with this example case, such that it prints out `hello   world!`, moves-from `s1`, and preserves `s2`:

```
int main()  
{
   std::string s1("world");
   std::string s2("!");

   std::string* ptr = allocate_array<std::string>(
      std::forward_as_tuple("hello"),
      std::forward_as_tuple(3, ' '),
      std::forward_as_tuple(s1.begin(), s1.end()),
      std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(s2))
   );

   for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      std::cout << ptr[i];

   std::destroy(ptr, ptr + 4);
   ::operator delete(ptr);
}
```

But, to say the truth, I am not completely confident that my solution is 100% correct.

Live demo is [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rkmcchZpLfViTffH).

**EDIT:** I added exception handling, which is pretty important here.